# Ajax form and google conversions - the tricky part

Tags: ajax, forms

For 2 weeks now i have tried to impliment the google conversion code to one of my ajax form landing page.

what i had in the ajax after success is

```
var google_conversion_id = **MYID**;
var google_conversion_language = "iw";
var google_conversion_format = "2";
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
var google_conversion_label = "**MYLABEL**";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
$.getScript( "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" );
```

i just didn't work. in firebug i could have seen the js loads after filling the form but no conversion on the page

now what i have ending up doing is adding iframe - hidden, to the success message after the ajax.

this is working but for me is not the right way i wanted to do it

**can anyone confirm my code is ok, or help understanding way it didn't work?**

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work using a dirty hack.

```
document.write = function(text) {
    $('#footer').append(text);
};        
$.getScript( "http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js" );
```

This is not ideal but it works for me until they remove the document.write from their script.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of google adwords snippet uses document.write (see line 14 of conversion.js) which does not work after your page is loaded. The way I solved my problem is to use an iframe as what you did.

Here are more discussions.

http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-help-advanced/browse_thread/thread/2ef3ee7dc5863e86?pli=1